# (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'DELL'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python

hey i am following  a tutorial for flask to make a simple blog website i am in the process of making simple database my code goes like this

```
 from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
 from datetime import datetime
 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql:///posts.db'
 db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class BlogPost(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key=True)
   title = db.Column(db.String(100) ,nullable = False)
   content = db.Column(db.Text , nullable=False)
   author =  db.Column(db.String(20) , nullable=False , default='Anonymous')
   date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime , nullable= False , default=datetime.utcnow)

def __repr__(self):
    return 'Blog Post' + str(self.id)
```

and in the terminal i am writing these commands

```
python
from app import db
```

but when i run this command in terminal

```
db.create_all()
```

I get this error

**sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'DELL'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")**

Please help thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To all those having this issue make sure you have correctly installed mysql and its running , in other opinion sqllite is also a good option but make sure it is installed too